# Do I have to report all the assets my s-corp disposed of on my personal taxes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, turbotax, schedule-k-1

My s-corp issued me a K-1 with a huge list of assets that were disposed of (not sold).  They are reported in box 17 as "K* STMT" (meaning code K, statement attached).  TurboTax is prompting me to enter all these items as part of my K-1 entry.

Do I really need to do this?  There are dozens of items and they were all written off years ago via section 179 and everything on the list was disposed of ($0 received for these items).  It will probably take a couple hours to enter it all and it's not going to change my tax situation at all.